# Update a smart pointer using a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I would like to update a smart pointer from a reference.

```
shared_ptr<My_Toy> my_toy_ptr;

// Something...

void update(shared_ptr<My_Toy> my_toy_ptr, My_Toy& toy){

     my_toy_ptr = &toy;
}
```

...but his code generates an error.

How can I do this operation?

Comment: Do not do this! Use the API.

Comment: You will need to use `make_shared`. Also your smart pointer is not passed by reference, so the function won't have any external effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass the address of a stack allocated object to a `std::shared_ptr`. `toy` will be destructed at the end of its scope and the `std::shared_ptr` will attempt to `delete` something that was not `new`d. The address held by a `std::shared_ptr` *must* be that of a dynamically allocated object (although a custom deleter can be provided, but that is not the case here).

To change the object that a `std::shared_ptr` is managing use [`std::shared_ptr::reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset).

Comment: I'm sorry, my example is wrong. I've just update the question with my real case.

Comment: @vdenotaris, what is being passed as the parameter `toy`? How is `update()` invoked?