# Smart pointer: set by reference, reset, set null, null-check or reset-check

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

For the first time, I'm using smart pointers in C++.
I've some question about `std::shared_ptr`:

1. Set pointer by reference:

   ```
   MyToy mytoy_1, mytoy_2;
   set_mytoy(mytoy_1, some_data);
   set_mytoy(mytoy_2, some_data); 

   shared_ptr<MyToy> ptr_mytoy(&mytoy_1);
   ```
2. Reset and new assignment:

   ```
   ptr_mytoy.reset(&mytoy_2);
   ```
3. Reset without assignment:

   ```
   ptr_mytoy.reset();
   ```
4. Set `NULL` (?):

   ```
   ptr_mytoy(nullptr);
   ```

Are these examples right?

How can I check if a smart pointer is *"empty"* (for instance, after `.reset()`) or if is `NULL`?

Comment: Please re-read the selected answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314544/update-a-smart-pointer-using-a-reference) carefully.

Comment: @juanchopanza In my previous question, I don't ask anything about null/reset check.

Comment: No, but you are still mis-using `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are these examples right?

The first two are wrong: they try to initialise and reset the `shared_ptr` with an object, not a pointer.

**UPDATE**: the question has now been changed to initialise them from pointers to automatic variables. This is still wrong: the `shared_ptr` will want to delete them, and it's an error to delete anything that wasn't created with `new`.

Usually, the object will be created using `new`, although it's better to use `make_shared` to create it for you:

```
// Good
auto ptr = make_shared<MyToy>();

// Not so good, but sometimes necessary
MyToy * mytoy_2 = new MyToy;
ptr.reset(mytoy_2);
```

The third is correct. It release the object from the pointer, deleting it if there are no remaining pointers, and leaving the pointer empty.

The fourth is either dubious or wrong, depending on what `null_ptr` is. If you mean `nullptr`, then it's incorrect and shouldn't compile. If it's a null-valued pointer to `MyToy`, then it leaves the `shared_ptr` non-empty, but not owning anything either.

> How can I check if a smart pointer is "empty" (for instance, after .reset())

```
if (ptr.use_count() == 0)
```

> or if is NULL?

```
if (!ptr)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, in my first two examples I forgot the `&`.

Comment: @vdenotaris: OK, that's wrong for a different reason. I'll update the answer in a moment...

Comment: Thank you so much. For the first example: I'm not using `new` because I have (in my real case) to associate my shared_ptr with a struct stored by value inside a container.

Comment: @vdenotaris: In that case you shouldn't be using `shared_ptr` at all, since you're not sharing control of the object's lifetime. The container has exclusive ownership of the object.

Comment: Is there a valid method to have the object's ownership from the container, or have I to use only values (and not pointers)?